# Functions for dataframes R

Tags: r, function

I am trying to build a function for a dataframe, but I get an error when I run it.

**Problem: How should I "apply" the function to a dataframe so that it works? Any workarounds for the atomic vector issue?**

The error is:

> Error in x$country: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

The function is:

```
occ_fction <- function (x)
{
    x <- subset(x, x$country== "DE")
    nace <- model.matrix(~ nace_code -1, data=x)
    x <- cbind(x, nace)
    rm(nace)
    # some more stuff here
}
```

This is how I apply the function:

```
mapply(occ_fction, mydata)
```

Comment: What is wrong with `occ_fction(mydata)` ?

Comment: What’s your rationale for using `mapply` here?

Comment: Can you make the data reproducible? `dput(occ_fction)`

Comment: Thank you! This works: occ_fction(mydata) !!!

Comment: If you make it into an answer, I will accept it: @Andrey Kolyadin